# Make my firstborn adapt to baby

Tags: toddler, newborn, parents, siblings

I have a lovely little boy that just passed the 1 year mark. I am blessed with such a child and am enjoying being a dad everyday. Now my second child is underway and while I am happy that they are very little years apart. I am also worried with the attention this new child will need.

Every child is different and I cannot predict how my second born child will be, it will (by experience) need alot of attention and dedication.

What is the best way to handle this situation, where my attention towards my firstborn child is not neglected and that he will accept his new sibling in the best manner possible. I don't want him to feel left out.

Is it bad parenting also that I am worried about this 4 months before this situation will even arise?

Comment: It's good parenting that you are thinking/worrying about this in advance. Gives you a chance to prepare. Never good worrying about it **after**